# Conseguir un determinado tag <link> según su orden de aparición en el documento

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Estoy intentando hacer una pequeña base de datos de LINKS de la página de Wikipedia sueca. Puedo obtener todos los link `hrefs` y se que el tercero de abajo hacia arriba es el link de la página actual, pero no se como limpiarlo para que solo me de ese link.

Este es el código:

```
import urllib.request
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#Download the wiki page

base_url = "https://tools.wmflabs.org/slumpartikel"


content = urllib.request.urlopen(base_url).read()

contentFeo = BeautifulSoup(content, "lxml")

for bonito in contentFeo.findAll('link'):
   print(bonito)
```

Comment: El tercero de abajo hacia arriba es https://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Det_(roman), pero el de la pagina es: https://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lasse_Vigen_Christensen, son diferentes

Comment: cada vez que corres el codigo te va dar un link diferente puesto que el url "https://tools.wmflabs.org/slumpartikel" es un bot que hace que cada ves que se corra te manda a una pagina aleatoria de wikipedia

Answer (score 0):

Si estas seguro que siempre el antepenúltimo link es el que buscas puedes simplemente hacer un indexado usando un indice negativo:

```
import urllib.request
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#Download the wiki page

base_url = "https://tools.wmflabs.org/slumpartikel"
content = urllib.request.urlopen(base_url).read()
contentFeo = BeautifulSoup(content, "lxml")
link = contentFeo.findAll('link')[-3]
print(link.get("href")))
```

---

No obstante parece ser que el link que quieres tiene el atributo `rel` igual a `"canonical"`, por lo que puedes hacer la búsqueda más eficiente con:

```
import urllib.request
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#Download the wiki page
base_url = "https://tools.wmflabs.org/slumpartikel"
content = urllib.request.urlopen(base_url).read()

contentFeo = BeautifulSoup(content, "lxml")
link = contentFeo.find('link',  {"rel": "canonical"})
print(link.get("href"))
```

En ambos casos, la salida será algo así:

> https://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Med_Maud_over_Polhavet

La variable `link` contendrá el tercer elemento por la cola de la lista retornada por `findAll`.

Comment: Muchas gracias me funciono la parte del codigo ya podre continuar y limpiaro

Comment: @BLH-Maxx he añadido una segunda opción que si el bot es consistente en su respuesta como parece es mucho más eficiente y simple, obteniendo de una vez solo el link que quieres. Recuerda que puedes marcar como aceptada una respuesta que resuelva adecuadamente tu duda  indicando a futuros usuarios con problemas similares su utilidad. Para saber como hacerlo y su funcionamiento puedes mirarte [¿Cómo funciona la aceptación de respuestas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427/15089). Un saludo.